# Which Battery pack use for Arduino TimeLapse dolly

Tags: arduino, batteries, stepper-motor

I'm trying to create a small TimeLapse Dolly during my spare time.  I'm planning to take away the dolly to film nature outside but I'm not sure which battery pack should I use.

I would like to maintain the complete system moving for about 2-3 hours, so I presume that using a 9V battery is not enough.

I have the following components:

- Arduino Duemilanove
- Stepper motor Driver (EasyDriver)
- Mercury Stepper Motor SM-42BYG011-25 (12V/0.33A)

I need assistance selecting a battery that will last for at least 2-3 hours, compatible with the component list above.

Comment: Which portion of your problem do you need assistance with?  If you want specific battery advice you might want to make that obvious at the end of your question.

Comment: I want a battery that last at least for 2-3 hours compatible with the previous components

Comment: 3 hours for a 0.33A at 12V is a 12V, 1Ah battery.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use a large [sealed acid battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRLA_battery)?  They come in 12V varieties and can support high output currents which would suit your stepper motors.

Comment: @David I would like to keep it as small as possible

Comment: You start by measuring the average current during a long period (eg. 3hrs). Take the average current, multiply that number by the number of hours required top operate the device, then multiply by 2 for a safe margin and you have the Ah rating you need to look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the motors are running the whole time you have 330mA for the motor. What the Arduino and driver will consume depends on a number of things but I'd hazard a guess of somewhere under 100mA so for a round number and a bit of a margin we'll say the whole lot is 500mA or 0.5A.

Driving everything from 12V is the easiest (but not most efficient) solution so for three hours of operation so you'll want a 12V 1.5Ah (3h x 0.5A) battery. That could be something like an SLA battery or maybe 10 x 1.2V AA rechargeable cells.

You can also get 11.1V LiPo battery packs that are often used in model cars etc and that should be close enough to drive your motors well and will be smaller than the above two options.

You'll need a charger for those options, there are a lot of choices so it really depends on whether you want to shell out for new charger or maybe use something like rechargable AA cells where you may already have a charger but using ten will be less convenient. For occasional use you could also use eight alkaline cells. You'll certainly need something larger than a 9V PP3 battery.